# How to fill gaps in point feature dataset - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point, vector-grid, gap

I have a point feature dataset that contains gaps, as can be seen in the picture below (1). I would like to fill the gaps with additional points with an equal distance (=0.5 meters). What is the most convenient way to achieve this?

Unfortunately, applying the "Create Fishnet" function does not result in the points being in the center of the created grid which would have been a workaround (picture 2).

Eventually, I would like to apply the solution into ArcPy.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Create Fishnet has oodles of parameters. There are several ways to alter the origin.

Comment: If black thing is a raster fill gaps by Con(IsNull(raster),1) and convert output to points. If it is not a raster, convert points to raster and set it as snap raster in environment settings.

Answer (score 1):

The initial point feature dataset can be used to create a fishnet grid. This fishnet grid can be used as input for the function "Feature To Point". The resulting point feature dataset can then be used to create another fishnet grid. This new fishnet grid can then be used again for the function "Feature To Point" so that all the gaps are filled with points, by the resulting point feature dataset.

Answer (score -1):

If the black layer is a raster dataset and you need to retain nearby values, you can look at using focal statistics to replace the Nulls using raster calculator (untested) `Con(IsNull("rasterlayername", FocalStatistics("rasterlayername", NbrCircle(15,15, "CELL",""), "MEAN", ""), "rasterlayername")` or Nibble https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-nibble-works.htm both require Spatial Analyst license.

If you have Spatial Analyst, you could convert the points to a raster and undertake the above or use one of the many point to raster interpolation methods such as IDW https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/an-overview-of-the-raster-interpolation-toolset.htm

Comment: Perhaps read my comments to OP and amend your solution to much simpler one.

Comment: Depends on if the OP wants to retain any attribute/value data from surrounding points/cells, eg is a DEM we are filling here, not clear in question what the purpose/data is.

Comment: I see your point. So he tried to use fishnet for interpolation, but failed.